# Debugging robot framework python keyword libraries

Tags: python, robotframework

For learning purposes I want to follow the execution path  in a robot framework python library.
Actually the [ssh library](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Connections%20and%20login)

What is the best way to do this?

I have looked at [debug lib](https://github.com/xyb/robotframework-debuglibrary/blob/master/DebugLibrary.py)   , which  seems to provide me with  the ability to set a breakpoint and spawn a new shell. However I want to examine  the execution flow, the stack and the variable values set. Something like pudb but triggered via pybot. Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use pdb with robot. How to do so is documented in the robot framework user guide, in the section titled [Using the python debugger (pdb)](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-the-python-debugger-pdb).

The example it gives is to add this where you want to set a breakpoint:

```
import sys, pdb; pdb.Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__).set_trace()
```

Comment: That did it, I opened lib/python2.7/site-packages/SSHLibrary/library.py  and added  import sys, pdb; pdb.Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__).set_trace()  to a keyword function.

Answer (score 3):

As I prefer to use ipdb more than pdb, then here is my way to use it with robot

```
import ipdb; ipdb.stdout.update_stdout(); ipdb.stdout.set_trace()
```

**Hint:** For some reason the **autocomplete** wont be working using pdb nor ipdb so if u care about the autocomplete u need to install `pdbpp` via `pip install pdbpp` then add this to your code

```
import sys
import pdb
for attr in ('stdin', 'stdout', 'stderr'):
    setattr(sys, attr, getattr(sys, '__%s__' % attr))
pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: Better: `export PYTHONBREAKPOINT=ipdb.sset_trace` then in your Python sources you use `breakpoint()`.  `sset_trace` is basically an ipdb-provided alias for `ipdb.stdout.update_stdout(); ipdb.stdout.set_trace()`

Answer (score 0):

You can debug directly in robot files, without creating a keyword:

```
Evaluate    pdb.Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__).set_trace()    modules=sys, pdb
```

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-the-python-debugger-pdb

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [RobotCode](https://github.com/d-biehl/robotcode) Visual Studio Code extension with the following in `launch.json` you can step into the Python code:

```
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "RobotCode: Run Current",
        "type": "robotcode",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "target": "${file}"
    },
    {
        "name": "RobotCode: Run All",
        "type": "robotcode",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "target": "."
    },
    {
        "name": "RobotCode: Default",
        "type": "robotcode",
        "request": "launch",
        "purpose": "default",
        "presentation": {
            "hidden": true
        },
        "attachPython": false,
        "pythonConfiguration": "RobotCode: Python"
    },
    {
        "name": "RobotCode: Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "presentation": {
            "hidden": true
        },
        "justMyCode": false
    }
]
```

The key parts are that `justMyCode` must be `false` and that `robotcode.debug.attachPython` is enabled as shown above because this is disabled by default.

See https://github.com/d-biehl/robotcode/issues/113